# Create a DataFrame from a String

Tags: python, pandas

How can I take a string and create a data frame.

Let's say the string I have is the following.

```
ss = "This is a string"
```

If I do the following, it produced an error.

```
pd.DataFrame(ss)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-4694a8452254>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.DataFrame(ss)

  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 404, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

However, if I try to create a series, it works.

```
pd.Series(ss)
Out[85]: 
0    This is a string
dtype: object
```

Comment: `pd.Series(ss).to_frame()`

Comment: or `pd.DataFrame([ss])`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO
df_string= pd.read_csv(StringIO(ss), sep=';')
```

Or:

```
df_string=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(ss))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see a `DataFrame` as a 2D thing (while a `Series` would be 1D).
In order to have a proper `DataFrame`, `pandas` needs index or columns or some dimension. Try the following:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(["Hello"])
       0
0  Hello
```

I wonder why you'd need this.